Transformer Model Not Training Correctly, Likely Tensor Size Mismatch
I am very new to Transformers and LLMs, and I am trying to re-purpose a model from this tutorial (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-code-the-transformer-in-pytorch-24db27c8f9ec#1b3f) for my dataset.
My data consists of a sequence of words and a single label (language id) attached to it. I want to train a bag-of-words style model so that the Transformer learns which language the words belong to, regardless of what order they are in.
My code looks like this:
Data Preprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
     filename='logfile.log',
     level=logging.INFO, 
     format= '[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
     datefmt='%H:%M:%S'
 )

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

lang_data = pd.read_csv('lang_data.csv')

labels = lang_data['langId']
sequences = lang_data['sequences']

word_to_token = {}
token_id = 1
total_X_tokenized = []

for i in sequences:
   for word in i:
       # Tokenize each word in a sequence
       X_tokenized = []
    
       if word not in word_to_token:
           word_to_token[word] = token_id
           token_id += 1
       X_tokenized.append(word_to_token[word])
    total_X_tokenized.append(X_tokenized)

max_sequence_length = 50  # Define maximum sequence length

for i in range(len(total_X_tokenized)):
    total_X_tokenized[i] = total_X_tokenized[i] + [0] * (max_sequence_length - len(total_X_tokenized[i]))

X_tensor = torch.tensor(total_X_tokenized, dtype=torch.long)
y_tensor = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)


Transformer Functions
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math

class Norm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, eps = 1e-6):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.size = d_model
        
        # create two learnable parameters to calibrate normalisation
        self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.size))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.size))
        
        self.eps = eps
    
    def forward(self, x):
        norm = self.alpha * (x - x.mean(dim=-1, keepdim=True)) \
        / (x.std(dim=-1, keepdim=True) + self.eps) + self.bias
        return norm
    
def attention(q, k, v, d_k, mask=None, dropout=None):
    
    scores = torch.matmul(q, k.transpose(-2, -1)) /  math.sqrt(d_k)
    
    if mask is not None:
        mask = mask.unsqueeze(1)
        scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, -1e9)
    
    scores = F.softmax(scores, dim=-1)
    
    if dropout is not None:
        scores = dropout(scores)
        
    output = torch.matmul(scores, v)
    return output


class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, heads, d_model, dropout = 0.1):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.d_k = d_model // heads
        self.h = heads
        
        self.q_linear = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.v_linear = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.k_linear = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.out = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    
    def forward(self, q, k, v, mask=None):
        
        bs = q.size(0)
        
        # perform linear operation and split into N heads
        k = self.k_linear(k).view(bs, -1, self.h, self.d_k)
        q = self.q_linear(q).view(bs, -1, self.h, self.d_k)
        v = self.v_linear(v).view(bs, -1, self.h, self.d_k)
        
        # transpose to get dimensions bs * N * sl * d_model
        k = k.transpose(1,2)
        q = q.transpose(1,2)
        v = v.transpose(1,2)
        

        # calculate attention using function we will define next
        scores = attention(q, k, v, self.d_k, mask, self.dropout)
        # concatenate heads and put through final linear layer
        concat = scores.transpose(1,2).contiguous()\
        .view(bs, -1, self.d_model)
        output = self.out(concat)
    
        return output

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff=2048, dropout = 0.1):
        super().__init__() 
    
        # We set d_ff as a default to 2048
        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dropout(F.relu(self.linear_1(x)))
        x = self.linear_2(x)
        return x

class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, heads, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.norm_1 = Norm(d_model)
        self.norm_2 = Norm(d_model)
        self.attn = MultiHeadAttention(heads, d_model, dropout=dropout)
        self.ff = FeedForward(d_model, dropout=dropout)
        self.dropout_1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout_2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, x, mask):
        x2 = self.norm_1(x)
        x = x + self.dropout_1(self.attn(x2,x2,x2,mask))
        x2 = self.norm_2(x)
        x = x + self.dropout_2(self.ff(x2))
        return x
    

class DecoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, heads, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.norm_1 = Norm(d_model)
        self.norm_2 = Norm(d_model)
        self.norm_3 = Norm(d_model)
        
        self.dropout_1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout_2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout_3 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
        self.attn_1 = MultiHeadAttention(heads, d_model, dropout=dropout)
        self.attn_2 = MultiHeadAttention(heads, d_model, dropout=dropout)
        self.ff = FeedForward(d_model, dropout=dropout)

    def forward(self, x, e_outputs, src_mask, trg_mask):
        x2 = self.norm_1(x)
        x = x + self.dropout_1(self.attn_1(x2, x2, x2, trg_mask))
        x2 = self.norm_2(x)
        x = x + self.dropout_2(self.attn_2(x2, e_outputs, e_outputs, \
        src_mask))
        x2 = self.norm_3(x)
        x = x + self.dropout_3(self.ff(x2))
        return x
    
import copy
class Embedder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.embed(x)
    
def get_clones(module, N):
    return nn.ModuleList([copy.deepcopy(module) for i in range(N)])

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model, N, heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.N = N
        self.embed = Embedder(vocab_size, d_model)
        #self.pe = PositionalEncoder(d_model)
        self.layers = get_clones(EncoderLayer(d_model, heads), N)
        self.norm = Norm(d_model)
    def forward(self, src, mask):
        x = self.embed(src)
        #x = self.pe(x)
        for i in range(self.N):
            x = self.layers[i](x, mask)
        return self.norm(x)
    
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model, N, heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.N = N
        self.embed = Embedder(vocab_size, d_model)
        #self.pe = PositionalEncoder(d_model)
        self.layers = get_clones(DecoderLayer(d_model, heads), N)
        self.norm = Norm(d_model)
    def forward(self, trg, e_outputs, src_mask, trg_mask):
        x = self.embed(trg)
       #x = self.pe(x)
        for i in range(self.N):
            x = self.layers[i](x, e_outputs, src_mask, trg_mask)
        return self.norm(x)
    
class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, src_vocab, trg_vocab, d_model, N, heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(src_vocab, d_model, N, heads)
        self.decoder = Decoder(trg_vocab, d_model, N, heads)
        self.out = nn.Linear(d_model, trg_vocab)
    def forward(self, src, trg, src_mask, trg_mask):
        e_outputs = self.encoder(src, src_mask)
        d_output = self.decoder(trg, e_outputs, src_mask, trg_mask)
        output = self.out(d_output)
        return output

Everything in the preprocessing step and the Transformer setup runs correctly and as intended. The issue arises when I try to train it.
Training Loop
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset, random_split
batch_size = 20
dataset = TensorDataset(X_tensor, y_tensor)

#EVERYTHING LOOKS FINE UP TO HERE


train_ratio = 0.8
val_ratio = 0.1
test_ratio = 0.1

# Calculate lengths of each subset
train_size = int(train_ratio * len(dataset))
val_size = int(val_ratio * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size - val_size

# Split dataset into train, validation, and test sets
train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size, test_size])

# Create DataLoader for each subset
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

src_vocab_size = len(word_to_token)+1  # Size of the source vocabulary
trg_vocab_size = len(np.unique(labels))+1  # Number of classes 
d_model = 128  # Embedding dimension
N = 4  # Number of encoder/decoder layers
heads = 8  # Number of attention heads

model = Transformer(src_vocab_size, trg_vocab_size, d_model, N, heads).to('cuda:0')
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)
num_epochs = 10000
num_classes = 360
val_losses = []
model.train()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    batch = 0
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # Zero the gradients
        inputs = inputs.to('cuda:0')
        labels = labels.to('cuda:0')
        #print(inputs)
        #print(labels.shape)

        #print(labels)
        
        outputs = model(inputs, labels, None #src_mask, None #trg_mask)

        labels = F.one_hot(labels, num_classes)
       
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
        #print("Completed for batch: " + str(batch))
        batch = batch + 1
    
    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataset)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")
    logger.info(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")

    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for val_inputs, val_labels in val_loader:
            val_inputs = val_inputs.to('cuda:0')
            val_labels = val_labels.to('cuda:0')
            val_outputs = model(val_inputs, val_labels, None, None)

            #print(val_labels)

            val_labels = F.one_hot(val_labels, num_classes)
            val_loss += criterion(val_outputs, val_labels).item()
            _, predicted = torch.max(val_outputs, 1)
            print("Max: " + str(torch.max(predicted)))
            total += val_labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == val_labels).sum().item()
            print("Correct:" + str(correct))

    val_loss /= len(val_loader)
    val_accuracy = 100 * correct / total
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    print(val_accuracy)

    if val_loss == min(val_losses):
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'directory/test_transformer_'+str(epoch+1)+'.pth')
        print(f'New Model Checkpoint Saved. Validation Loss is: {val_loss:.4f}')
        logger.info(f'New Model Checkpoint Saved. Validation Loss is: {val_loss:.4f}')

The Training and Validation losses never improve, which is likely due to the model predicting on only 20 classes as opposed to the entire vocab size, which is 360. I know something (or multiple things) is off with my training loop, as the output shape is not what I expect (Tensor.shape([20, 20, 360]), and the validation loop only predicts from 0 to 19. I'm guessing it's somehow training on the batch data instead of the vocab.
As you can probably tell with the format of this training loop, my background is mostly in CNNs and other neural nets, not LLMs, so I would also appreciate any input you have on how the format of the training loop differs between the two.
Thank you for all of your help!
I've tried to look into Transformer documentation and the shapes/values of the inputs, outputs, and labels tensors. The inputs and labels tensors look correct (inputs contains a tokenized sequence whereas labels consists of an integer value corresponding to a language id). The outputs tensor does contain values that look to be correct, but the losses never improve, so something must be off there.

Since you're more familiar with image data, you might find the example code here informative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77729577/21896093 It's a simple implementation of multi-head attention for MNIST digits data. The main differences from your code are: it uses image data as opposed to text (though apart from tokenisation they are dealt with in a similar way); it's just an encoder (though you can stack a second attention block configured as a decoder); and it's minimal in that it doesn't have residual connections or layer normalisation (though I think they'd be straightforward to add).

Interesting, will look into that. Thank you for the recommendation!
